# DApp on Node2 accessing smart contract deployed by Node1

Tags: private-blockchain, contract-invocation, dapp-development, json-rpc, server-side

Node 1(Desktop) deployed a contract on private blockchain. From node2(Laptop),I want to interact with the contract.

But I failed at 'web3.version.getNetwork(err, netId)' function.This function throws json-rpc server error.

I am getting Network id value as undefined.But when i tried this on Node1 itself, it is working. To access json-rpc server from Node2, Do I have to configure anything on My Node2?

Answer (score 1):

Deploying a contract on the network by any node in that network makes it accessible by all the nodes in the network. The JSON-RPC error is probably due to the second node (laptop) not being properly configured or lacking synchronization with the first node.